# How do I turn on "god" mode?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, cheats

Is there a cheat or hack to turn on god mode in Modern Warfare 3's Survival mode?  I'm playing on a PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are no cheats for Modern Warfare 3 survival mode.  Further, Modern Warfare 3 uses Valve Anti-Cheat (VAC) on PCs, as well as having a [dedicated hacker busting team](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/113334-Modern-Warfare-3-Getting-Dedicated-Anti-Cheating-Teams), so if you do manage to find a cheat or hack online, I'd advise against using it, lest you find your XP reset, get banned from all things multiplayer in the game, or potentially worse!